# Eclipse: C/C++ Plugin Download Link?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, ide

I'm downloaded the Java EE version of Eclipse 3.5.1. Can I now use it to edit C/C++ with the proper plugin?

I went to **Help** >> **Install New Software** but I don't know which URL to use to get the C/C++ plugin. I can't find it on the Eclipse website either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ May be you need to download C/C++ IDE.

Comment: yes, and if I can't find a plugin I'll do this, but I'd rather not have a bunch of different versions of Eclipse on my system.

Comment: Agreed, having several eclipse versions is painfully confusing.

Answer (score 56):

Just wanted to update the thread with the Juno (Eclipse 4.2) plugin link since I had some trouble finding it.

To install it on your existing eclipse go to **Help** >> **Install New software** >> **Add** and add the link: `http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/juno`

If you need another version you can find it [here](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php).

Note that the update URL has changed from tracking the Eclipse name to an independent numeric version beginning with Luna:

CDT for Eclipse Luna - http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/8.6
CDT for Eclipse Mars - http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/8.8.1
CDT for Eclipse Neon - http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/9.0

Comment: Just a note: that link gives a 404 in a web browser, but entering it in the Install New Software dialog worked fine.

Comment: I would like a C plugin without c++, since I would never use c++.

Answer (score 9):

1-In Eclipse (Juno) , go to  " Help/Install new software" .

2- Install dialog appears , in front of "Work with:" input at the top row of dialog  press the "Add..." button.

3- in the "Add Repository" dialog type something as name( for example CDT) and in the "Location" input box type: " http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/juno " and press OK.

If your connection to internet be good, after a while you should have "CDT main features" and "CDT Optional Features" appeared in the list.

Answer (score 2):

You can [download the package](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php) you want according to your eclipse version.

The CDT can either be installed as part of the Eclipse C/C++ IDE packaged zip file or installed into an existing Eclipse using the "Help->Install New Software->Add(near work with)" and provide following required URL:

> http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/indigo.

Answer (score 2):

Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Ubuntu: 14.04

Go to Help -> Install New Software

There is a text-box named "Work with".

http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/8.6

Wait for 5 minutes (Pending will appear)

Then, select "CDT main features" and "CDT optional features"

Click Next

Accept the agreement license

It will start downloading.

Comment: The release number per Eclipse version is given at http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php .

Answer (score 2):

Alternative way to install CDT was tested under Ubuntu 16.04.2, Eclipse Neon3
Help > Eclipse Marketplace...
Enter "cdt" in Search > Find
Scroll down to locate **Eclipse C/C++ IDE CDT x.x**, click Install
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may have a problem with Galileo's download if you're behind a proxy.
If it comes to it, [this](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.webtools/msg18858.html) might help.

Comment: It's not an issue of being unable to download the plugin - I can't even find the URL.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.easyeclipse.org/site/plugins/eclipse-cdt.html

This is what you are looking for...

Comment: But this is EasyEclipse... can I use this with the normal Java EE distribution I got from www.eclipse.org?

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried the same with gallelio or helios but when tried installing CDT pluggin for the recent eclipse Indigo, it worked fine. It works with both ADT and CDT plugins simultaneously. 
The download URL for plugin is http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/indigo.

Answer (score 1):

Installing CDT depends on version of eclipse you have.

This page will help you to download appropriate CDT based on the version on eclipse you have.

http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php
You can either manually download the plugin then provide the local path in **Help->Install New Software** or you can directly provide the repository url.

For example if you are using  **Eclipse Helios** then you can directly provide the CDT eclipse repository URL as  http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/helios.

Answer (score 0):

Tip:

try to get the .zip file for the plugin and paste it in dropins folder at eclipse/dropins because if you ever need to re install eclipse, this zip will be handy

https://eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php

look for archives there, and download the latest one!

[like this one](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/tools/cdt/releases/9.0/cdt-9.0.0.zip)