# Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers -> Download JDT

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-jdt

Sorry for my poor english.

I downloaded and installed the Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers environnement. 
Today I would like to use my eclipse for C/C++ (always) but also Java.

I didn't find the Java plugin (JDT ?) for my current eclipse environnement.

I have to download Eclipse IDE for Java Developers or it's possible just to add a plugin?? (so How program in C+C++ and Java)..

Thank you very much for your help

Morgan

Comment: check this link you might find your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151567/eclipse-c-c-plugin-download-link

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible i use eclipse STS for developing spring, grails and JavaEE at the same time so try this link http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/ you can always refer to the source.